# "The constructor being called isn't a const constructor", but constructor is not called with `const`

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to try put `TextFormField` in the row expanded widget, but I can't seem to put `TextFormField` anywhere there

```
Column(
    children: [
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Full Name'),
        subtitle: TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
            hintText: 'Full Name',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 5,
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
        title: Text('Department'),
        subtitle: TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                hintText: '  Department',
              ),
            ),),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child:ListTile(
        title: Text('Year Of Study'),
        subtitle:  TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                hintText: '  Year Of Study',
              ),
            ),),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

This is one example of the code I find to put `TextFormField`s side by side, but got this error:

```
The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.
```

`TextFormField`'s constructor isn't being invoked with `const` in this case.  How do I fix this error?

Comment: listTile takes whole width of the screen, soo using Expanded causing error. For ur case, use SizedBox, Column, row widgets. Remove expand & ListTile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code your problem will be resolved you were using the one ListTile outside the row that is why that problem was occurring.

```
Column(
    children: [
      const SizedBox(
        height: 50
      ),
      Row(

        children: [
      
       Expanded(
       child: ListTile(
        title: const Text('Full Name'),
        subtitle: TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
            hintText: 'Full Name',
          ),
        ),
      ),
       ),
      
          Expanded(
            child: ListTile(
        title: const Text('Department'),
        subtitle: TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8),),),
                hintText: 'Department',
              ),
            ),),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5
          ),
          Expanded(
            child:ListTile(
        title: const Text('Year Of Study',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.5,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
        subtitle:  TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                hintText: '  Year Of Study',
              ),
            ),),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a parent Widget with a `const` keyword; check the `Column`'s parents and remove any `const` until the issue is resolved.